# printing column numbers in python

Tags: python

How can I print first 52 numbers in the same column and so on (in 6 columns in total that repeats). I have lots of float numbers and I want to keep the first 52 and so on numbers in the same column before starting  new column that will as well have to contain the next 52 numbers. The numbers are listed in lines separated by one space in a file.txt document. So in the end I want to have:

1 53 105 157 209 261

2

...

52 104 156 208 260 312

313 ... ... ... ... ...

...(another 52 numbers and so on)

I have try this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
line = f.read().split()
line1 = "\n".join("%-20s %s"%(line[i+len(line)/52],line[i+len(line)/6]) for i in range(len(line)/6))  
print(line1)
```

However this only prints of course 2 column numbers . I have try to add line[i+len()line)/52] six time but the code is still not working.

Comment: If possible please post a few sample lines of your input file.

Comment: -0.0082    0.0017    0.0006    0.0076    0.004    0.0088    -0.0073    0.004    0.0088    -0.0073    -0.004    -0.0088    0.0073    -0.004    -0.0088    0.0073    0.0036    0.0036    -0.0036    -0.0036    -0.0077    0.0113    -0.0077    0.0113    0.0077    -0.0113    0.0077    -0.0113    0.0023    -0.0001...

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Please edit the input file data into the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in range(52):
    for col in range(6):
        print line[row + 52*col],   # Dangling comma to stay on this line
    print    # Now go to the next line
```

Granted, you can do this in more Pythonic ways, but this will show you the algorithm structure and let you tighten the code as you wish.

Comment: this code works if i use : row in range(len(line)), however I have 8112 numbers and the cod can not read all of them for some reason. Is there a way to increase the amount of number it can read?

Comment: This is a separate question.  Please post the input, the failing source code, and the full error message.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve